# dynamic block in module parameters

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create terraform that calls a module and I need to be able to include a dynamic block in the parameters of the module call

this is the sort of thing i'm trying to do

**main.tf**

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "../../modules/eks"
  node_groups = [
    {
      name = "gp1"
      gp_instance_count = 4
    },
    {
      name = "gp2"
      gp_instance_count = 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "node_groups" {
  type = list(object({
      name = string
      gp_instance_count = number
    }))
}
```

**eks.tf**

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"

  dynamic self_managed_node_groups {
    for_each = var.node_groups
    content {
        self_managed_node_groups.value["name"] = {
          capacity_rebalance = true 
          use_mixed_instances_policy = true 
          desired_size = self_managed_node_groups.value[".gp_instance_count"]
        }
   }
}
```

What I'm hoping for here is to iterate around var.node_groups and create a "self_managed_node_groups" section.

This would pass the following to the module

```
        gp1 = {
          capacity_rebalance = true 
          use_mixed_instances_policy = true 
          desired_size = 4
        } ,
        gp2 = {
          capacity_rebalance = true 
          use_mixed_instances_policy = true 
          desired_size = 2
        }
```

I'm getting the error

````
  87:         self_managed_node_groups.value["name"] = {

An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.```
````

if I hardcode the self_managed_node_groups.value["name"] value then I get the error

```
Blocks of type "dynamic" are not expected here.
```

It feels like what I'm trying to do is quite straightforward and i'm just missing something simple.

I'd appreciate any help at all on this!

Comment: This is not allowed in HCL2. You will have to approach this differently.

Comment: oh :/

Can you suggest a way i can approach this?

Comment: Actually to step back even further: blocks are not allowed at all inside `module` blocks in HCL2; much less dynamic blocks (this is due to the type conversion from the schema struct in Go without getting bogged down in details). I think you need to revisit what you want to achieve here, because `node_groups` should be a `map` type.

Comment: Ok, so i need to pass a map.

I'll review and try to find another way

Thanks